# Unable to boot Win10 USB on Lenovo T410

Tags: linux, windows-10, installation

I have an older Lenovo T410 that i've successfully used for Linux-based distros for years and now I'm trying to install Win 10. The machine currently has Fedora 29. I should note that it's legacy BIOS only.

I've got a valid copy of Win10 and have tried using the following methods:

- Using 'dd' from the iso to the drive (which has always worked in the past.) This makes a UDF drive that is seemingly unbootate from the Lenovo, but I can boot from my desktop (AMD Ryzen 1700) no problem.
- Creating a vfat (FAT32) drive which is compatible with the BIOS. This failed because this filesystem type cannot handle files larger than 4GB.
- Creating an NTFS drive with the parition boot flag set to 'on'. This just hung at a blinking cursor.
- Creating a LinuxUDF drive and copying the files over. This had the Lenovo tell me the drive was unbootable.

It feels like I'm missing something simple but it's been over 10 years since I last actively used Windows so perhaps there's something different now.

Comment: Try the Windows qo Media Creation tool. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Can he use the media creation tool if he doesn’t currently have a PC running Windows?

Comment: Probably not (haven't tried it under wine), but someone else could for him.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another bootable USB again using Rufus and then make changes in your bios and then try reinstalling win 1o because I think that the only problem is in bios.